# Backbone, one field not set when calling view.render after model.save

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have the following problem. On a user-event (click on .twitterDefault) I call save event with

```
twitter : {
                    handle : handle,
                    ignore : false
}
```

Then the success function gets called and I set fields on the model (klout, twitter and tester). All fields are set (logging statements all print out appropiate objects.

However, then I call view.render() and here twitter is not set anymore. I have no idea why, there is no sync happening after the save so twitter does not get overwritten (additionally I made sure twitter is also saved on the server before the success method gets called).

Any help greatly appreciated!

Code as follows (stripped to improve readability)

> $(function() {
>
> ```
> var ContactModel,
>     ContactModelCollection,
>     ContactView,
>     ContactCollectionView,
>     contacts,
>     contactCollectionView;
>
> //base model
> ContactModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
>     defaults : {
>     },
>     initialize : function() {
>     }
> });
>
> ContactModelCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
>     model : ContactModel,
>     url : '/api/contacts',
>     comparator : function(contact) {
>         return contact.get('strength_of_relationship');
>     },
>     initialize : function() {
>     }
> });
>
> ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
>     tagName : 'li', //attempting to create a new element
>     render: function() {
>         var compiled_tmpl = _.template($('#contact-template').html());
>         var html = compiled_tmpl(this.model.toJSON());
>         console.log('model.get("twitter")=('+JSON.stringify(this.model.get('twitter)'))+')');
>         console.log('model.get("klout")=('+JSON.stringify(this.model.get('klout'))+')');
>         console.log('model.get("tester")=('+JSON.stringify(this.model.get('tester'))+')');
>         this.$el.html(html);
>         console.log('rendered view successfully)');
>         return this;
>     },
>     initialize: function() {
>         console.log('contactView initalized');
>         this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
>         this.model.bind('destroy', this.remove, this);
>     },
>     events: {
>         'click .twitterDefault' : 'assignDefaultTwitterHandle',
>     },
>     assignDefaultTwitterHandle : function(event) {
>         var handle = $(event.currentTarget).data('twitter');
>         this.assignTwitterHandle(handle);
>     },
>     assignTwitterHandle : function(handle) {
>         console.log('model assignTwitterHandle. handle='+handle+')');
>         var view = this,
>             model = view.model;
>         model.save({
>             twitter : {
>                 handle : handle,
>                 ignore : false
>             },
>             id : model.get('id')
>         }, {
>             error : function() {
>                 console.log('saving twitter handle failed');
>             },
>             success : function(model, response) {
>                 console.log('response=('+JSON.stringify(response)+')');
>                 if(response.error) {
>                     console.log('error on server ='+response.error);
>                 }
>                 if(response.twitter) {
>                     console.log('twitter is set');
>                     var twitter = {
>                         handle : handle,
>                         tweet : response.twitter,
>                         age : new Date()
>                     };
>                     console.log('setting twitter to '+JSON.stringify(twitter));
>                     model.set('twitter', twitter);
>                     model.set('tester', 'tester');
>                     console.log('twitter after setting it = '+JSON.stringify(model.get('twitter')));
>                     console.log('view\'s model twitter after setting it = '+JSON.stringify(view.model.get('twitter')));
>                 }
>
>                 if(response.klout) {
>                     console.log('klout is set');
>                     var klout = {
>                         topics : response.klout
>                     }
>                     console.log('setting klout to '+JSON.stringify(klout));
>                     model.set('klout', klout);
>                 }
>                 if(response.twitter || response.klout) {
>                     console.log('Rerendering view after setting klout/twitter');
>                     view.render();
>                 }
>             }
>         });
>     }
> });
>
> contacts = new ContactModelCollection;
>
> ContactCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
>     el : $('#suggestions-list'),
>     initialize : function(){
>         contacts.bind('add', this.addOne, this);
>         contacts.bind('reset', this.addAll, this);
>         contacts.bind('all', this.render, this);
>     },
>     render : function(){
>         console.log('contactcollectionview render');
>     },
>     addOne : function(contact) {
>         console.log('addOne');
>         var view = new ContactView({model: contact});
>         var el = view.render().el;
>         console.log('el=('+el+')');
>         $('#suggestions-list').append(el); 
>     },
>     addAll : function() {
>         console.log('addAll');
>         contacts.each(this.addOne);
>     }
> });
>
> contactCollectionView = new ContactCollectionView;
>
>
> App.contacts = contacts;
> App.contactCollectionView = contactCollectionView; });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the scope of the `render` function.
Depending from where is called, `this` takes a different value.

To warranty that always `this` is pointing to the View scope, add to your `initialize`:

```
_.bindAll(this,"render");
```

Also, it's not good habit to call view.render manually. You should let the events do their work. [Model save](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) already triggers some events. Just listen to them to update your View.

Comment: Thanks for your answer corbacho. I don't think the problem is the scope. Firstly, values 'klout' and 'tester' are printed out as expected. Additionally, the change is also bound to the render method, 'twitter' is still undefined. I tried it out with commenting the manual render (in the success callback) which didn't change anything (except one render call less).